# What is this Error of import testing_copy means?

Tags: python, syntax-error

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
import testing_copy
File "/home/runner/day-5-1-test-your-code/testing_copy.py", line 41
def test_2(self):
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
**
Can somebody tell me whats the problem and solution

I was trying to to just a code exercise so its a question from there and till now I haven't changed any thing

Comment: there was a syntax error in your code, no one can help you without seeing the code

Comment: Does you file end after line 41? I line that has the start of defining a method but no method body? Perhaps adding a properly indented `pass` or `...` on line 42 might help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code this error is in response to, or at least the lines it mentioned (line 25 and 41).

But as for what the error means:
"Unexpected EOF implies that the interpreter has reached the end of our program before executing all the code. This error is likely to occur when: we fail to declare a statement for loop ( while / for ) we omit the closing parenthesis or curly bracket in a block of code."

So either you're missing a for/while loop or you need to rerun your notebook (I'm assuming?) from the beginning. Maybe there's a variable or two being reassigned or something when you run this part of the exercise. But there's no way for anyone to know what it could be unless you post the code that gave you the error.

Since you said this is a code exercise and you didn't change anything, there are too many possibilities for what could have caused it.

1. maybe if you save your work as it is right now and then restart your kernel and run all cells until that point, you'll be fine.

OR

2. maybe you copied the exercise form somewhere but the source/website has formatting that doesn't translate well in your notebook or CLI. (like if i copied and pasted the code this page, I would get an error since the for loop is not indented properly, aka wrong syntax: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html )

OR

3. If you copied and pasted a sample exercise from a website/etc., maybe you didn't get all the code and forgot a curly bracket/parenthesis/etc.

OR

something else...

Again, no one can give you an exact answer unless you edit the post to include the code/cell that gave you the error.